# Binary search doesn't return the correct index in an array

Tags: java

I tried for hours, but I can't understand why my search doesn't bring back the right value. Somehow it skips the **bold code** in the last iteration. I know I could just copy someones else's code entirely, but I wanted to find the mistake in my code.

```
public class binarysearch {


  public static int findvalue(int arr[], int value) {
    int left = 0;

    int right = arr.length - 1;

    int middle = (right + left) / 2;

    while (value != arr[middle]) {

      if (value > arr[middle]) {
        left = middle;
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
      } else if (value < arr[middle]) {

        right = middle;
        middle = (left + right) / 2;

      } else {
        return -1;
      }
      break;
    }
    return middle;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    int value = 9;

    int indexFromArry = findvalue(arr, value);
    int valueFromArry = arr[indexFromArry];

    System.out.println("index is: " + indexFromArry);
    if ((indexFromArry >= 0) && (indexFromArry < arr.length)) {
      System.out.println("value searched by index is: " + valueFromArry);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls first fix you indentations. The way it currently is (e.g. method code on the same indentation as the method declaration), makes it very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would execute that statement given the chance, but you are breaking out of the `while` loop too soon.

Specifically, you have an unnecessary `break` statement immediately after the `else  {return -1;}` .   That `break` statement stops the search after the first binary cut, so get rid of it.

Offhand, i think there are further issues with your algorithm, that might lead to infinite loops - eg  if the search value is not present, etc.  So compare your code against other references - eg even https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm will do for this (*)

(*) apologies to any Wikipedia proponents !